# Can't View Database Contents through an AWS ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

Good day guys, I created an Elastic Beanstalk application environment on AWS, and then I deployed an ASP.NET MVC application to the existing Elastic Beanstalk environment I created ealier.
In the Web.Config file I added a connection string for my RDS Instance I created on AWS. Here is the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="friendsEntity" connectionString="Data Source=hmsdb-instance.cmv6c98nhaap.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;Initial Catalog=friends;User ID=admin;Password=**********;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I also created a model for my database. The application deploy perfectly, but whenever I tried to view or add data to my database through my application I get this error:

**Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.**

Can you guys please help me? If you need to see my model, view and controller please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]
I'm able to connect to Sql Server Management Studion with the user name and password of my rds instance.

Comment: Your application threw an unhandled exception.  If you take a look at the `Error.cshtml` view under the **Shared** folder - you can expose the stack trace of the exception there.

Comment: I'm looking at the view right now, but how do I expose the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: You can output the exception by adding `@Model.Exception.ToString()` to the view.  Note that this has the side effect of exposing the internal error detail to end users - so only do this as a debugging excercise.  Updated your question with the exception that is getting thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Finally guys I found a way out. What happen is that I created a security group and I assign that security group to my db instance. But there were some settings in the inbound rules of the security group that I needed to take care of.

All I needed to do was to add the inbound rule of "All TCP" and my application now works fine. Don't fully understand if this is harmful or help, but if works for now.

Need your views if there are things that I need to consider in going forward. Thanks guys (@BrendanGreen). Great community!